# Vertex Operators with nonlinear terms in Conformal Field Theory

Tags: conformal-field-theory

Suppose that we have a simple theory described by the following Hamiltonian
$$
H=\sum_{k>0}k a_k^{\dagger}a_k,
$$
where $[a_k,a_{k'}^{\dagger}]=\delta_{k,k'}$. We can usually define the Vertex operators in the following way
$$
V_{\alpha}(x)=:\exp[i\alpha Y(x)]:
$$
where $:*:$ describes the normal ordering of operator $*$, and the operator $Y$ may be defined in the form
$$
Y(x)=-i\sum_{k>0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}(e^{-ikx}a_k^{\dagger}-e^{ikx}a_k).
$$
We know how to calculate the Operator product expansion and correlations for those vertex operators.

My question then is very simple, and as follows:

If we redefine the operator $Y'$ in another form (with the same Hamiltonian):
$$
Y'(x)=-i\sum_{k>0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}[e^{-ikx}(a_k^{\dagger}+\sum_{k1,k2,k3}:a_{k1}^{\dagger}a_{k2}^{\dagger}a_{k3}:\delta_{k+k3,k1+k2})-h.c.].
$$
In that case, whether it is possible or meaningful to evaluate the the Operator product expansion and correlations for those vertex operators for the new operators $V_{\alpha}(x)=:\exp[i\alpha Y'(x)]$:, e.g.
$$
V_{\alpha}(x) V_{\alpha}(y), \langle V_{\alpha}(x) V_{-\alpha}(y)\rangle...?
$$

Is anybody know the answer and relevant references?